# Ошибка program does not contain a static 'main'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

При попытке публикации сайта на ASP.NET Core мне выпадает ошибка program does not contain a static 'main' , однако этот метод имеется

```
namespace PersonalArea.WebUI
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                await RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(userManager, rolesManager);
            }

            host.Run();
        }


        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема, и как это исправить? Скажите пожалуйста

Comment: `async Task Main` - это вроде в последних версиях только появилось. Ваш сервер такое поддерживает?

Comment: Я пытаюсь опубликовать это на IIS, хотя бы для примера, но там стоит последняя версия всего

Comment: Убрал аснхронный мейн в ответе, попробуйте его - если заработает, то у вас просто не поддерживается фича на IIS

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить свой Main метод

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(userManager, rolesManager).Wait();
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```